# What is the "sieve and limiting process" technique? (From a paper of Ërdos on polynomials with power-free values)

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Let $f$ be a primitive integral polynomial of degree $d$. In [Arithmetical properties of polynomials](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-28.4.416/abstract), Ërdos says (page 417) that the integers $n$ for which $f(n)$ is $d$-th power free have positive density,

> by a simple application of the Sieve of Erathostenes and an easy limiting process.

(He makes a similar remark in page 418).

I have nearly zero knowledge of analytic number theory. I have looked at two previous papers on a similar subject, one by Ricci and another by Nagell, which may apply this technique, but I couldn't find it (Ricci's paper seems strangely organized to me, while I do not understand Nagell's because I cannot read German).

Can you explain what Ërdos meant, with some detail? Can you give some guiding examples to learn the technique?

Comment: You should look at how $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(n)|n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+p^{-s}) =\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ proves the square-free integers (those with [$\mu(n)\ne 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)) have density $\lim_{s \to 1^+} \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mu(n)|n^{-s}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}} =  \frac{1}{\zeta(2)} > 0$. The same kind of argument holds in any free commutative monoid (with unique factorization in irreducibles).